# How can I prove that I am very good but in a Phone Interview? (Foreign with an accent)

Tags: interviewing, management, human-resources, united-states

So I work with a company and I am open for better opportunities. I got a call today that the CEO of a Software Development company wants to speak with me as a phone interview tomorrow at 1 p.m. I said ok and the phone call went fine.

I have some concerns what if I have been asked why do I need to change the company:

- Should I say the personal stuff that are part of the reason of me looking for another job
- Should I speak about the technical and professional stuff that are part of the reason
- Should I just keep it ambiguous as like every human looks for new jobs and better opportunities and this sort of thing.

I am shy, quite and when I speak in English I have the worst accent ever. My main concern though, is that there won't be a coding test which is my best part. I believe that I should be tested because that is my strongest point and I can impress them. I don't feel representative or good in anything except programming. **How can I prove that I am good at what I do but wanting better opportunities?**

I don't know why I am nervous..

Comment: What do you mean by "deserve better opportunities" - do you mean that you want them? or that you feel you should have them because you are a better coder?

Comment: Don't bad mouth your employer.  This is a big warning sign for the new employer.

Comment: @ender I meant I want them I did not mean to be arrogant. I like my team a lot and they are really good. I learned from them what I know now. I just don't like the stressful manager

Comment: "When I speak in English I have the worst accent ever". But you said at the beginning of your question that the phone call went fine. Maybe your accent is not as bad as you believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to find ways to get past phone interviews](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15545/i-want-to-find-ways-to-get-past-phone-interviews)

Comment: @Brandin it was a 1 minute call and I was just being informed. I am good in listening. It was yes/no questions. Today I need to explain and inform with details. Technical I am good with terms, but not with a regular or normal chat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking the accent barrier in a telephone interview](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14390/breaking-the-accent-barrier-in-a-telephone-interview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd argue a few points here:

1. Don't say anything to your prospective employer as you said it here.

You don't "deserve" a better opportunity, nor a worse position. It sounds egotistical to hear one mention they "deserve better".

2. Inexperienced / uneducated managers:

These things happen, and often great leaders are not as skilled at technical work. But citing this as a problem for you says you don't handle adversity or diversity well.

3. Jr. Staff

A great employee teaches and mentors jr. staff. That a proficient staff member (allegedly at this juncture) blames the jr. staff for a myriad of problems instead of investing in them is alarming!

> I don't feel representative or good in anything except programming.

In 2016, **this is not enough!**

How does one create accurate time requirements without being able to clarify technical requirements? Or own one's own mistakes to make the company function smoother the next go around (or help the junior staff do the same).

That said, there are better ways to think of or phrase your reasons for looking elsewhere.

Some quick ideas/ examples:

1. Seeking additional creative freedom
2. "I am looking for more seasoned colleagues to learn more advanced concepts which aren't currently available to me being the senior developer"

Comment: _I don't feel representative or good in anything except programming._ Not only is it not enough: you should make sure to never say this during an interview.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking up some interview tips on Google & YouTube. There are so many and not enough time for us to describe them all. Overall though, keep it professional and don't talk negatively about anything if it all possible (frame negatives in a positive manner (i.e. we failed on XYZ project, but when we got ABC, we were so determined to succeed we not only met expectations, we exceeded them ahead of schedule and under budget)).

For your accent, just talk slowly and as clearly as possible. They will appreciate it and be able to understand you more clearly. Take your time. Ask them if they understood what you said at the end of your statements with phrases such as "If that makes sense." or "You know what I mean?". Use them sparingly on some level. Don't be afraid to ask for an e-mail address to follow-up with and to touch base on some points in text/writing as that might clear up any confusion they may have. NOTE: At the end say the following EXACTLY:

"Is there anything you did not understand? Is there anything you would like clarity on or me to explain more? I know my accent sometimes presents a language barrier and part of my excellent communication skills is to ensure individuals know I want to help them if they don't understand me. Please do not hesitate."

This way if they have questions or are unsure, you can address those issues.